# About separation property of hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let N be a complete Riemannian manifold and M be a complete hypersurface in N. M is said to have separation property if N\M is disjoint union of 2 connected open sets in N. Under what reasonable assumptions on N (like simply connected or vanishing homology or cohomology)can ensure that M must have separation property? Thank you.

Comment: Any closed, null-homologous hypersurface of a closed manifold is separating (think about the intersection product). This is probably much weaker than you want, though. (Note in particular that this implies that if $H_{n-1}(M) = 0$, every hypersurface is separating.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $M$ and $N$ are orientable, it suffices for the first [Betti number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) of $N$ to be zero.

To see this, let $U$ be a tubular neighborhood of $M$, let $V = N-M$, and consider the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in (say) reduced de Rham cohomology
$$
\cdots \;\leftarrow\; H^1_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(N) \;\leftarrow\; \tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(U\cap V) \;\leftarrow\; \tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(U) \oplus \tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(V) \;\leftarrow\; \tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(N)
$$
Since $M$ and $N$ are orientable, the intersection $U\cap V$ has two components, so $\tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(U\cap V)\cong\mathbb{R}$.  Since $M$ and $N$ are connected, we also know that $\tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(U) = \tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(N) = 0$.  Thus, the exact sequence above simplifies to
$$
\cdots \;\leftarrow\; H^1_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(N) \;\leftarrow\; \mathbb{R} \;\leftarrow\;  \tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(V) \;\leftarrow\; 0
$$
But $V=N-M$ has two components if and only if $\tilde{H}\,\!^0_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(V) \cong \mathbb{R}$, and this is guaranteed as long as $H^1_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{dR}}(N)=0$.

Comment: Note that this is just a special case of what Mike pointed out in the comments above, since $[M\hookrightarrow N]\in H_{n-1}(N,\partial)=H^1N \cong \mathbb Z^{b_1N}$ is nullhomologous if $b_1N=0$

Comment: If N is orientable and smooth  and every orientable hypersurface has the separation property, then Hn−1(N;Z) must be zero. This follows because every element of Hn−1(N;Z) can be represented by a connected orientable hypersurface, at least if n>2, and the separation property implies that M is null homologous. A non-orientable hypersurface is not separating because its normal bundle is not trivial (because N is orientable).